# Drawing QPolygonF to QSGGeometry

Tags: qt, 2d

I'm trying to draw a polygon using `QSGGeometry/QSGFlatColorMaterial`. If I draw a rectangle with right corners, then everything works correctly:

```
QPolygonF polygon;

// Rectangle with right corners
polygon << QPointF(0, 0)
        << QPointF(230, 0)
        << QPointF(230, 230)
        << QPointF(0, 230)
        << QPointF(0, 0);

QSGGeometry *geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), polygon.count());
QSGFlatColorMaterial *material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial();

material->setColor(QColor("red"));
QSGGeometry::Point2D *vertices = geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();

for (int i = 0; i < polygon.count(); i++) {
    QPointF point = polygon.at(i);
    vertices[i].set(point.x(), point.y());
}
```

Correct result:
[image: Correct result]
But if I try to draw a rectangle with rounded corners:

```
// Rounded rectangle
polygon << QPointF(0, 10)
        << QPointF(0.78585, 6.10755)
        << QPointF(2.92893, 2.92893)
        << QPointF(6.10755, 0.78585)
        << QPointF(10, 0)
        << QPointF(220, 0)
        << QPointF(223.892, 0.78585)
        << QPointF(227.071, 2.92893)
        << QPointF(229.214, 6.10755)
        << QPointF(230, 10)
        << QPointF(230, 220)
        << QPointF(229.214, 223.892)
        << QPointF(227.071, 227.071)
        << QPointF(223.892, 229.214)
        << QPointF(220, 230)
        << QPointF(10, 230)
        << QPointF(6.10755, 229.214)
        << QPointF(2.92893, 227.071)
        << QPointF(0.78585, 223.892)
        << QPointF(0, 220)
        << QPointF(0, 10);
```

Then I get this result:
[image: Incorrect result]
**I need the outline of the rectangle to be filled with color. What could be the problem and how to fix it?**

I have no idea how to fix this.

Full example:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Some VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appSome
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appSome
    URI Some
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
    SOURCES view.h view.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(appSome
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include "view.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_SCALE_FACTOR", QByteArray("3"));

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(8);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    qmlRegisterType<View>("Some", 1, 0, "View");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load("qrc:/Some/Main.qml");
    return app.exec();
}
```

view.cpp:

```
#include "view.h"
#include <QSGGeometry>
#include <QSGFlatColorMaterial>

View::View()
{
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemHasContents);
}

QSGNode *View::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, UpdatePaintNodeData *)
{
    QPolygonF polygon;

    /*
    // Rectangle with right corners
    polygon << QPointF(0, 0)
            << QPointF(230, 0)
            << QPointF(230, 230)
            << QPointF(0, 230)
            << QPointF(0, 0);
    */

    // Rounded rectangle
    polygon << QPointF(0, 10)
            << QPointF(0.78585, 6.10755)
            << QPointF(2.92893, 2.92893)
            << QPointF(6.10755, 0.78585)
            << QPointF(10, 0)
            << QPointF(220, 0)
            << QPointF(223.892, 0.78585)
            << QPointF(227.071, 2.92893)
            << QPointF(229.214, 6.10755)
            << QPointF(230, 10)
            << QPointF(230, 220)
            << QPointF(229.214, 223.892)
            << QPointF(227.071, 227.071)
            << QPointF(223.892, 229.214)
            << QPointF(220, 230)
            << QPointF(10, 230)
            << QPointF(6.10755, 229.214)
            << QPointF(2.92893, 227.071)
            << QPointF(0.78585, 223.892)
            << QPointF(0, 220)
            << QPointF(0, 10);

    QSGGeometry *geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), polygon.count());
    QSGFlatColorMaterial *material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial();

    material->setColor(QColor("red"));
    QSGGeometry::Point2D *vertices = geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();

    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.count(); i++) {
        QPointF point = polygon.at(i);
        vertices[i].set(point.x(), point.y());
    }

    QSGGeometryNode *node = new QSGGeometryNode();
    node->setGeometry(geometry);
    node->setMaterial(material);

    return node;
}
```

view.h:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class View: public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit View();

protected:
    virtual QSGNode* updatePaintNode(QSGNode*, UpdatePaintNodeData*) override;
};

#endif
```

Main.qml:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import Some

Window {
    width: 250
    height: 250
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    View {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
    }
}
```

**UPD:** With the suggested changes (`DrawTriangleFan` drawing mode and `QPointF(150, 150)` at the start of `polygon`) I get this result:
[image: Unsuccessful attempt]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I made a minimal project in QTCreator with this problem: https://easyupload.io/d3j0vw

Comment: Please put the code as correctly formatted text in the question -- *not* as an external link.

Comment: Note that the default drawing mode is `QSGGeometry::DrawTriangleStrip` whereas you appear to be simply providing the polygon line boundary.  I suspect your original 'rectangle' code worked by accident.

Comment: Try adding an extra point `QPointF(150, 150)` at the start of `polygon` and then set the drawing mode to [`QSGGeometry::DrawTriangleFan`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsggeometry.html#DrawingMode-enum).

Comment: I've updated my question with the full code. Unfortunately, the proposed changes did not solve the problem, I have attached a screenshot at the end of the question.

Comment: Note that my comment said to use `QSGGeometry::DrawTriangleFan` *not* `QSGGeometry::DrawTriangleStrip`.

Comment: I'm sorry, the result in the screenshot is from DrawTriangleFan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255907/discussion-between-posix-and-g-m).